# If the Nth number in a cell is odd or even, the formula should write either 1 or 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I need to determine whether or not a specific subject in my study is male or female. Whether someone is male or female is determined by one specific number in the cell- if it is odd or even. The string goes xxxxxxxxxYx (the 10th number of an 11 digit cell). In the original cell the odds are male and evens are female. So I need to determine which it is and then based on that write 0 for male and 1 for female.

e.g. the formula from cell B1 would check if the value in cell A1 is e.g. xxxxxxxxx7x (the subject is male), and then write 0 (for male).

i.e. something like this xxxxxxxxx8x      1     (evens = female = 1)

I was thinking it would somehow work if IF and ISEVEN formulas, but I couldn't figure out how to search for a specific ordered value inside a cell.

Thank you very much for your help and patience :)

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as correct.  It is something only you can do and it will close this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MID()` to extract part of a string and `INT()` to convert `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`:

```
=INT(ISEVEN(MID(A1, 10, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

wouldnt something like:

```
 IF(ISEVEN(RIGHT(cellref, 2), "Female", Male))
```

Work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the mid() function:

```
=IF(MOD(--MID(A1,10,1),2)=0,1,0)
```

Comment: @VilleRitola please choose one and mark it as correct. Click on green check mark by answer you choose.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISODD(B6),"Male",IF(EVEN(B6),"Female"))
```

I want the cell to remain blank intile it is written into. now even if you don,t, type, it gives the option of male or female. cell should be empty until written.